# What are some *slick* UI libraries/frameworks/tools for, non-MFC, Win32 C++ apps?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, skinning

What is a really good Windows, C++, UI library, framework, or tool that will allow me to very simply and easily add a *slick* look & feel to my native C++ win32 application?

Also;

- *Slick* means skinnable with window background images, fancy buttons, shadows, all that jazz.
- This is non-MFC
- Supporting Windows XP and beyond
- Royalty free licensing (we expect a lot of installs)
- VS2008

Comment: Windows GUI in C++ is always wrong, in my mind. I'd look into C#, it has a large number of (extremely easy to use) GUI libraries.

Comment: If you can use .NET, then WPF probably fits the bill.

Comment: @dauphic: "Windows GUI in C++ is always wrong" says the guy that never tried Qt 4.

Comment: If I'm only targeting Windows, I would still consider C# and .NET superior to Qt.

Comment: We all agree that C++ for the GUI is wrong, but it's done, and I'm just doing clean up & beautification.  FWIW-I believe the original requirements were for pre-XP, which I believe is why they went /w C++.

Comment: @dauphic: To prove that *insert gui library name here* is better than Qt 4, you would need to provide alternative implementation of programs included QtDemo - using that library. Code should be kept as readable as possible. *At least* examples in "Demonstrations" section. @John MacIntyre: "We all agree that C++ for the GUI is wrong" I don't agree. If Qt 4 isn't "right", what else do you want?

Comment: @SigTerm-I didn't even know about Qt before this question, but I'm grateful for the Qt response and am investigating it as we speak.

Comment: Im going to disagree on principal here. The "slick" UI for Win32 native apps is to use the native Widget set. Theyre not skinnable - and thats the point - the obey the users preferences for color, font size and usability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) has all you are asking for.

Comment: +1 for Qt: you can even theme all your buttons, and use the fancy Windows Vista/7 wizard window things. Be sure to check out the QML/QtQuick stuff in the 4.7 beta. It adds even more drawing functionality.

Comment: Quick question; it seems like everything I'm looking at suggests, Qt is used as the underlying foundation for the app.  Is Qt a good choice for just adjusting GUI look & feel for an existing app?  thx.

Comment: Yes, you can use as much or as little as Qt as you like. You can use it purely for the Gui and keep your application logic as non-Qt. You can also use it to handle most of the Gui but also use native controls. You've got a huge amount of flexibility.  Re: licensing - check the docs carefully as there's a dual licence, so while you can use the LGPL version for free, you can't later switch to the commercial version. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352896/qt-commercial-licenses) for more discussion

Answer (score 4):

Another library you might consider is [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/). Open source + small binary footprint = was good for a large number of downloads and installs.

Comment: I really like WTL, but since they use standard windows controls it is not easily skinneable.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility you might want to consider is [Ultimate++](http://www.ultimatepp.org/index.html).

Comment: Do you recommend Ultimate++? How does it compare to Qt?

Comment: Once upon a time, I kind of preferred it over Qt from a coding viewpoint (Qt's ownership semantics always struck me as messy), but it's been long enough since I used Ultimate++ that I'm extremely hesitant to make a recommendation either way about it any more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Scott Hanselman, I have heard of [Hilo](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Hilo), even though it looks like its for Windows 7 or newer.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but you're right, it does look like it's Windows 7.  Thanks anyway.